# Seaborn lineplot, show months when index of your data is Date

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a Kaggle dataset ([link](https://storage.googleapis.com/kagglesdsdata/datasets/116573/334386/museum_visitors.csv?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=gcp-kaggle-com%40kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20211213%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20211213T192756Z&X-Goog-Expires=259199&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=9977939728779ee1fdb82bb9047adeea77903ec49a413029fcab9e14c650961a0daf50019609fabfeddd8e4b0ec9d8d5b77405e943a751d0453f91c76b3076be759f2ac6a7664215335cecdb22e26e8fb18c0019c3949659bbd190c925cdc8d0b6f56fbe31f0aa1995836d37c8a7ffb0cd3267ef461fedd058844fe81ab1686611de0f4ceff0bf1ed3c20e7b88f8ce995ebde9f59d197f2c8b13c26117203bb9d8d89105dcf2e85ab6a1b4043a5cb36d9615fc88622dd66bd2d79131f883eb0817b36c1265ce99b6a4de09a9d912f4d3afad9b645c39b21dd44f5037dae0c1c12547101c02753b8d948b0f6a07f5fdf9c3f593139ec9cbb42dbb23ae09e229c5)).
I read the dataset, and I set the `Date` to be index column:

```
museum_data = pd.read_csv("museum_visitors.csv", index_col = "Date", parse_dates = True)
```

Then, the `museum_data` be like:

| Date | Avila Adobe | Firehouse Museum | Chinese American Museum | America Tropical Interpretive Center |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-01-01 | 24778 | 4486 | 1581 | 6602 |
| 2014-02-01 | 18976 | 4172 | 1785 | 5029 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2018-10-01 | 19280 | 4622 | 2364 | 3775 |
| 2018-11-01 | 17163 | 4082 | 2385 | 4562 |

Here is the code I use to plot the `lineplot` in seaborn:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (20,8))
sns.lineplot(data = museum_data)
plt.show()
```

And, this is what the result looks like:
[image]

What I want to know is that, how I can show multiple (not all, for example, first month of each season) months per year in x-axis.

Thank you all for your time, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`MonthLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator) and perhaps [`ConciseDateFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.ConciseDateFormatter) to add minor ticks with a few months showing, something like the following:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

...

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,8))
sns.lineplot(data = museum_data, ax=ax)

locator = mdates.MonthLocator(bymonth=[4,7,10])
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator))
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit** (closer): you can add the following to show January as well:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b\n%Y'))
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit 2** (there's probably a better way but I'm rusty):

```
length = plt.rcParams["xtick.minor.size"]
pad = plt.rcParams['xtick.minor.pad']
ax.tick_params('x', length=length, pad=pad)
```

[image]

Comment: looks wonderful. I am just wondering, how I can include Jan, in a clean way?

Comment: See the edit. I think I just need to adjust the major tick length to get the January month names to align with the other months.